# How can I query list of objects in DynamoDb (using CLI)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamo-local, dynamodb-queries

Below is what the table structure looks like in DynamoDb when I scan the table using

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "hotel" --endpoint-url  http://localhost:8088

{
    "Count": 2,
    "Items": [
        {
            "dc": {
                "N": "0"
            },
            "sw": {
                "L": [
                    {
                        "N": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "dc": {
                "N": "0"
            },
            "sw": {
                "L":[]
            },
        }
    ],
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

Now I want to query the table where `sw: []`. I am using following query to retrieve the results.

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name "hotel" --key-conditions  file:////tables/key1.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8088 where
```

**key1.json**

```
{
  "sw":{
    "ComparisonOperator":"EQ",
    "AttributeValueList": [ {"L":[]} ]
  }
}
```

But I get following error

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element
```

Please suggest how can I query the table to retrieve the results.

Comment: There is a nice example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html#examples

Comment: Does your query work from AWS / DynamoDB (rather than localhost)?

Comment: I tried this as per the example `aws dynamodb query --table-name "hotel" --projection-expression "sw" --key-condition-expression "sw = :v1" --expression-attribute-values file:///tables/key.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8088` and I get this error `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema`

Comment: I tried filtering using sw in interface which dynamodb provides for tables but for field "sw" being a list i could not find any options.

Comment: Can you run a `aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name "hotel"` and edit your question to add the result?  Im confident we can help you if we know more details about your table.  Tx!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have structured you table its hard to query the array by its fields.Try to save each Item as a row.